# Is there a prettier way to check for DBNull when creating a string array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, null

Right now I am using the following method:

```
string[] AudienceTags = ((string[])(relResults["NEVCOAudienceTag"].GetType() == typeof(DBNull) ? null : relResults["NEVCOServiceTag"]));
```

But this is pretty long.  Is there a slick way that I don't know of that I should be using to achieve the lines above.

FYI relResults is a [ResultTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.search.query.resulttable.aspx) object, which comes from a [FullTextSqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.fulltextsqlquery.aspx).  This is all SharePoint related, so I don't have the same options that I would if this were a straight SQL Server query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write `relResults["NEVCOServiceTag"] as string[]`.

Since `DBNull.Value` isn't a `string[]`, it will return `null`.

Comment: Personally I'd also add a check that relResults contains the key "NEVCOServiceTag" too

Answer (score 1):

ResultTables inherit from IDataReader, so each IDataRecord in the result should have an `.IsDBNull` method.